# How to make restful api using py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I think my question is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259333/how-to-make-python-api-using-py2exe) but I do not really understand the answer provided hence the new question.

I am trying to build an executable(.exe) file for restful api. I am using `py2exe`. Below is the structure of my restful api directory :-

```
the_server/api/test/resources/mydata.py
the_server/api/test/resources/model.py
the_server/main.py
```

I am using celery and mongodb inside `mydata.py` to queue some function and store data inside mongodb. Both need some external command to run for example celery needs to be run using `celery -A mydata worker --loglevel=info` while for mongodb, the connection needs to be open with command `mongod` (please correct me if I am wrong)

The `main.py` is simply the script to run the server by calling the `mydata.py` script.

My question is is there any other parameters that I need to add inside `setup.py` before running `python setup.py py2exe` for example command for running celery worker and mongod?

Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.